# What is the difference between the definition of a 'sheaf' given in these notes vs. the usual definition?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The definition that is new to me that I have not see anywhere is in the beginning of the third chapter of these [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf) by J.S. Milne. The usual definition I'm speaking of is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Formal_definitions).

My question is are these two definitions the same, and if yes, how?

Comment: [This definition of sheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Formal_definitions) is in more general framework, where as [this one](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf) is more particular. Milne is talking about actual functions $f: U \to k$. So the "locality" and "gluing" conditions are *almost automatic*, provided we can talk about "restriction" for open covers, and that is the third assumption (see example 3.5 also).

Comment: @Krish Thank you, your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia definition is more general. The differences can be summarised as:

- The notes are using sheaves of sections to $k$ in $\mathrm{Set}$: a subsheaf of the sheaf defined by setting $\mathcal{O}_V(U)$ to be all functions $U\to k$. With the general definition you can have, for example, $V$ being a point but $\mathcal{O}_V(V)=k^2$.
- The notes require the $\mathcal{O}_V(U)$ to be a unital $k$-subalgebra of the unital $k$-algebra of functions $U\to k$.

Wikipedia defines $\mathbf C$-valued sheaves, so you could think of it as a sheaf valued in the category $\mathbf C$ of unital $k$-algebras. But then you're relying on the extra fact that $\mathbf C$ is concrete and has the limits you'd expect. If it gives the wrong definition for non-concrete categories then why bother using any $\mathbf C$ but Set? See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/11911. Milne's notes often seem to prefer to give explicit axioms to clarify subtleties about all the different categories/topologies/limits/etc.